# Unable to connect to the MQTT broker

Tags: go, mqtt, paho

I wrote the following code to subscribe to a topic

```
func run(c *cli.Context) error {
    customFormatter := new(log.TextFormatter)
    customFormatter.TimestampFormat = time.StampMilli
    customFormatter.FullTimestamp = true
    log.SetFormatter(customFormatter)
    log.Info("begin running")
    username := c.String("xxxxxxxxx")
    password := c.String("xxxxxxxxx")
    broker := c.String("tcp://address:port")
    clientID := newRandClientID()
    opts := MQTT.NewClientOptions()
    opts.SetClientID(clientID)
    opts.AddBroker(broker)
    opts.SetUsername(username)
    opts.SetPassword(password)
    opts.SetOnConnectHandler(onConnected)
    opts.SetConnectionLostHandler(onConnectionLost)
    tlsconfig, err := newTLSConfig()
    if err == nil {
        opts.SetTLSConfig(tlsconfig)
    }
    client := MQTT.NewClient(opts)
    if token := client.Connect(); token.Wait() && token.Error() != nil {
        log.WithField("MQTT", token.Error()).Info("failed to connect MQTT broker")
    }
    defer client.Disconnect(250)

    sigChan := make(chan os.Signal)
    exitChan := make(chan struct{})
    signal.Notify(sigChan, os.Interrupt, syscall.SIGTERM)
    log.WithField("signal", <-sigChan).Info("signal received")
    go func() {
        log.Warning("stopping wlora")
        exitChan <- struct{}{}
    }()
    select {
    case <-exitChan:
    case s := <-sigChan:
        log.WithField("signal", s).Info("signal received, stopping immediately")
    }
    return nil
}
```

When I run it I get the following error:

> level=info msg="failed to connect MQTT broker" MQTT="Network Error : dial tcp: missing address".

What can I do to solve the problem ?

Comment: What is `broker` set to? (you are setting this via `c.String`  but don't provide this function so its unclear what value you end up using). It will be easier to assist if you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example); if you don't want to show the address then perhaps use `tcp://test.mosquitto.org:1883`.

Comment: What does your `c.String()` function do?  You pass `c` in as a `cli.Context` Type, but you don't show what the Type is/does.  `opts.AddBroker()` accepts String types.

Answer (score 0):

Seemingly your `func (c *cli.Context) c.String(key string) string` function accesses a map provided by the context.

The above function signature is a guess, as it is nowhere provided.

So `tcp://address:port` seems to be a key to some corresponding value that does not exist in that map, resulting in most likely the `broker` variable to be set to the empty string.
In order to debug, you may want to either use a debugger to see the value of the `broker` variable or add a `fmt.Printf("'%s'\n", broker)` statement after your `broker` has been set. That variable will most likely be empty resulting in the output `''`.

Nonetheless, as mentioned by the comments, it's unclear what the `c.String(...)` function does.